# Aliases for going to directory of a file and executing command in that directory

Tags: linux, bash, bash-alias

I am trying to write two command aliases one to take a file not directory path and cd into its directory. My attempt below is.

```
alias godir='cd $(dirname $1)'
```

however this leads to

```
bash cd: {file path} not a directory
```

but when I manually specify a file path it works.

I then would expand this to something like

```
alias execdircmd='cd $(dirname $1) && $2 $1'
```

so I could pass a single file to a command move into its directory and then run a command on it without adding the directory to my PATH.

Any advice/fixes?

Comment: I suggest to use a function. See `help function`.

Comment: This very concept goes against the "unix way".  You are trying to work around basic unix security (which is why `.` is not in your path by default on unix).  You will surely find a workaround but ask yourself if you should?

Comment: BTW, I mean no offense.  I have just worked with many unix gurus that would cringe seeing what you are trying to do.

Comment: [An alias replaces text with text](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30950/108618), there is no logic.

Comment: No offence taken. Thank you for your help guys I have solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Answer involved writing a basic function.

Thanks [Kamil Maciorowski](https://superuser.com/users/432690/kamil-maciorowski)

```
execdircmd () {   cd $(dirname $1); $2 $1; }
```

Comment: This code will misbehave sooner or later. Improvements: (1) [quote right](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618); (2) [double dash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376/108618); (3) abort if `cd` fails.